# How to: Assign a unique number to every entry in a list?

Tags: c#, list, random, xna, tile

What I want is to make tiles.  These tiles (about 30 of them) should have a fixed position in the game, but each time I load the game they should have random numbers that should affect their graphical appearance.

I know how to use the `Random` method to give a single tile a number to change its appearance, but I'm clueless on how I would use the `Random` method if I were to make a list storing the position of multiple tiles. How can you assign each entry in a list a unique random number?

I need this for my game where you're in a flat 2D map, generated with random types of rooms (treasure rooms, arena rooms etc.) that you are to explore.

Comment: itereate through your list and assign random value using key value pair.

Comment: Random numbers don't have to be *unique*

Comment: Seems to me 90% of the questions here about random numbers are one of three things: (1) Badly seeding the RNG (like putting srand() inside the loop). (2) Needing random numbers that add to a constant sum, and (3) confusing random number generation with shuffling. This is number 3--you don't want tiles to have random locations, you want them to have all the standard locations in random order. Keep those coordinates in an array, shuffle them, and apply the to the tiles.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It's super easy to use and should work well for you, if I read your question right.

Answer (score 1):

if you have something like this:

```
public class Tile 
{
     public int Number {get;set;} 
     ...
}
```

you can do it like this:

```
var numbers = Enumerable
  .Range(1, tilesList.Count)  // generates list of sequential numbers
  .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()) // shuffles the list
  .ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < tiles.Count; i++) 
{
    tile[i].Number = numbers[i];
}
```

I know, that `Guid` is not a `Random` alternative, but it should fit this scenario.

Update: As long as answer was downvoted, I've wrote simple test, to check if Guids are not usable for shuffling an array:

```
var larger = 0;
var smaller = 0;

var start = DateTime.Now;

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    var nextGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    if (nextGuid.CompareTo(guid) < 0)
    {
        larger++;
    }
    else
    {
        smaller++;
    }

    guid = nextGuid;
}

Console.WriteLine("larger: {0}", larger);
Console.WriteLine("smaller: {0}", smaller);

Console.WriteLine("took seconds: {0}", DateTime.Now - start);

Console.ReadKey();
```

What it does, it counts how many times next guid is smaller than current and how many times is larger. In perfect case, there should be equal number of larger and smaller next guids, which would indicate, that those two events (current guid and next guid) are independent. Also measured time, just to make sure, that it is not too slow.

And got following result (with 10 million guids):

> larger: 5000168
>      smaller: 4999832
>      took seconds: 00:00:01.1980686

Another test is direct compare of Fisher-Yates and Guid shuffling:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).ToArray();
        var originalNumbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

        var foundAfterListUsingGuid = new List<int>();
        var foundAfterListUsingShuffle = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var foundAfter = 0;
            while (!originalNumbers.SequenceEqual(numbers.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())))
            {
                foundAfter++;                    
            }

            foundAfterListUsingGuid.Add(foundAfter);

            foundAfter = 0;

            var shuffledNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).ToArray();
            while (!originalNumbers.SequenceEqual(shuffledNumbers))
            {
                foundAfter++;
                Shuffle(shuffledNumbers);
            }

            foundAfterListUsingShuffle.Add(foundAfter);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Average matching order (Guid): {0}", foundAfterListUsingGuid.Average());
        Console.WriteLine("Average matching order (Shuffle): {0}", foundAfterListUsingShuffle.Average());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Random _random = new Random();

    public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
    {
        var random = _random;
        for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
        {
            // Pick random element to swap.
            int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
            // Swap.
            T tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i - 1];
            array[i - 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
```

By "direct compare" I mean, that I'm producing shuffled sequence and try to shuffle again to get same sequence, and assume, that the more tries I need to produce same sequence, the better random is (which is not necessary mathematically correct assumption, I think it is oversimplification).

So results for small set with 1000 iterations to reduce error, was:

> Average matching order (Guid): 5015.097
>   Average matching order (Shuffle): 4969.424

So, Guid performed event better, if my metric is correct :)

with 10000 iterations they came closer:

> Average matching order (Guid): 5079.9283
>   Average matching order (Shuffle): 4940.749

So in my opinion, for current usage (shuffle room number in game), guids are suitable solution.

Comment: But say, if I want to use `Random` because I might want multiple treasure rooms, how would I do it? I know this isn't *unique* but by unique, I meant that all of the list's entries should have the same number.

Comment: @Neophyte - "by unique, I meant that all of the list's entries should have the same number" - that's a complete opposite definition of unique I think :) As long as Enumerable.Range creates list of numbers going from 1 to titlesList.Length, all numbers in that list are unique. Then I use Guid to shuffle them, it gives unpredictable enough sequence, still keeping uniqueness.

Comment: I have worked much of it out, but I still don't understand what the last piece of code does (the `for`-loop). I have my variables like this: `room_position` (list keeping track of vector2s) and `room_type` (an int describing the rooms' properties). So I want to random which number gets which position. The `var` seems to take all of the rooms and give them a randomized number based on how many rooms there are, right?

Comment: GUIDs are not random, they are simply unique, and should not be used as random number generators.

Comment: @Servy> I've updated my answer with some very simple tests of randomness.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of 30 consecutive numbers, mirroring your array of tiles. Then pick an array-shuffling solution you like from, say, here for instance:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1778021.aspx/1

Then tile[23]'s number will be numberArray[23].

Comment: Rather than just posting a link to an answer, please include the details of the answer in your post itself (with attribution as appropriate).  It's important that answers be self contained and that, while using links is okay, a reader should not be required to follow links to get an answer to the question.